# In app purchase restoration access denied error

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

One of our app users just reported a weird error message while trying to restore the in app purchases, but I haven't been able to reproduce it.

[image]

"Access denied.

purchase the software application first"

any thoughts?

Comment: Ask Google about "appstore itunes error purchase software first"